Stars are not displayed in orthographic mode
Well, in general, the stars in the sky made through the nodes in the world tab are not displayed in orthographic mode. Everything is fine in the other modes. Please help me fix this.

There is nothing to fix - the world background is not a flat 2D image (the texture is, but not the world), so it cannot be shown as background in orthographic view.  See the answer to this question: Orthographic Cam with HDRI in background.
